What to do with nail holes from removed zinc strips?
I've got zinc strips on my tar shingle roof.  They are all curled up, tearing loose at the ends, and lifting up the shingles so I need to remove them.  What do I do with the holes from the nails that were holding the zinc strips on?  Put a fresh nail back in the hole to plug it up and roof sealant over it or just sealant over the hole?  Will the nails work loose and lift the shingles if I put them back in?
Reasonably sure the zinc strips were added after the shingles were already installed so those nails aren't needed to hold the shingles in place.

Don't add nails. That would add complexity, which is counter to a good seal. Just force roofing sealant* into the holes and leave a dab on top, then press the shingles down. It's best to do this kind of work while the roof is cool for easier separation and reduced foot traffic damage.

* Silicone caulk is not roofing sealant. It doesn't bond particularly well and doesn't remain gooey and flexible. Use a purpose-made product.

Do you have a recommendation for specific brand/type of roofing sealant that I can get in the US?

Brand recommendations are off topic here. Just about anything your store has is fine.

Would you expect this repair to last as long as the rest of the roof or is it a weak point that's going to fail in a few years?

It's a permanent repair.
